# Delayer along with Splitter, messages not processing serially

Tags: java, spring-integration

My requirement is to process(call Webservice) the List of messages in a serial fashion one after the other. If first message is successful then only process the 2nd message and so on.

I am using Splitter here to split the messages. Inside Splitter I have used Delayer (not persistence).

Problem is as soon as 1st messages goes in to delayer, 2nd message in the list start processing, without waiting for the first message to be completed.

I believe this is happening because delayer doesn't block the threads.

Is there as way I can achieve this functionality by using Splitter and delayer?

Comment: You should explain why do you use delayer there at all

Comment: I have to wait for some event to complete, and then only call webservice. I am using delayer so that I can check the database for event completion. Once event is completed i call webservice.

Answer (score 1):

The delayer is designed that way; it schedules the message to be processed some time in the future. If you simply want to slow down the rate at which you process splits; simply add a POJO service (invoked by a service activator) that has a `Thread.sleep(...)` and returns the input message.

```
public Message<?> sleeper(Message<?>) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```